# How can I have more than one GUI X Terminal running in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xterm

In Linux you can access up to 6 different terminals plus the X display.

In Mint, the shortcut for the X display is *ctrl + alt + f8* instead of *f7*. Since *f7* shows me log messages of VirtualBox and Timidity++, I'm assuming its the text version of the X display.

I'm using Cinnamon as a WM and would like to use Unity in a different terminal.

Is that even possible?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple%20x%20sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows: go to your first free tty, say 1, by means of Ctrl+Alt+F1, login, then issue the command

```
 startx -- :1 vt9
```

The new X session will open in F9. And so on.

Comment: Apparently there are complications sometimes. For example, [this person](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=113002) found that whether it worked correctly or not depended on the window manager he was using. Of course, he could have been doing other things wrong.

Comment: @JasonC Right. But not a very knowledgeable person, IMHO. BTW, I use kdm.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I should be doing. But my new X session is empty. Only the cursor and my background are on screen.

Anyways, thanks a ton. It's a great start.